# error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `insert variable name', expecting `.'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I get this error message in Unity 5

> error [CS1525](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hdyz4dw(v=vs.90).aspx): Unexpected symbol `insert variable name', expecting`.'

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class jumpControll : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public bool jump;
    public float jumpHeight;



    // Use this for initialization

    public IEnumerator jumpUp (float jumpHeight) 
    {
        jumpHeight = 3.0f;
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x,
          transform.position.y + jumpHeight, transform.position.z);
    }

    public IEnumerator jumpDown (float jumpHeight) 
    {
        jumpHeight = 3.0f;
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x,
           transform.position.y - jumpHeight, transform.position.z);
    }

    public IEnumerator jumpTest()
    {
        jumpUp(float jumpHeight);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        jumpDown(float jumpHeight);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        jump = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space);
        if (jump == true)
            jumpTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does the error occur? What line number/character location? Is it occurring at build time or run time?

Answer (score 0):

There are several things which are not going to allow your code to compile.

First of all, you specify that your `jumpUp` and `jumpDown` methods are going to return an `IEnumerator` however, you do not return one.  If you do not need to wait for a period of time in `jumpUp` and `jumpDown` than they should have a return type of `void` rather than `IEnumerator`.

```
public void jumpUp (float jumpHeight) 
{
    jumpHeight = 3.0f;
    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x,             
                                     transform.position.y + jumpHeight,
                                     transform.position.z);
}

public void jumpDown (float jumpHeight) 
{
    jumpHeight = 3.0f;
    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x,
                                     transform.position.y - jumpHeight, 
                                     transform.position.z);
}
```

Secondly, in your `jumpTest` method, you attempt to call `jumpUp` and `jumpDown` passing in your `jumpHeight` variable.  You do not need to use the `float` keyword in front of the variable you are passing, because you are not creating a new variable, instead you are using one that already exists.

```
public IEnumerator jumpTest()
{
    jumpUp(jumpHeight);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    jumpDown(jumpHeight);
}
```

Finally, in order for an `IEnumerator` method to work properly, you need to call it by using `StartCoroutine()`.  So for example, in your update method:

```
void Update () 
{
    jump = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space);
    if (jump == true)
        StartCoroutine(jumpTest());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    public IEnumerator jumpUp(float jumpHeight)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + jumpHeight, transform.position.z);
    }

    public IEnumerator jumpDown(float jumpHeight)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - jumpHeight, transform.position.z);
    }

    public IEnumerator jumpTest()
    {
        jumpUp(3.0f);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        jumpDown(3.0f);
    }
```